# How to show aggregated value in a new column in ag-grid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, aggregate, ag-grid

I need to show the aggregated value (max) of "Gold" in a separate column in ag-grid. This is my ag-grid
[image]

and i need to show the aggregated value (max) of "Gold" as[image]

I used **aggFunc** but its not working properly.

`{
  headerName: "Gold",
  field: "gold",
  aggFunc: "max",
  enableValue: true,
  width: 100
}`

But this is not working. I need to display the aggregated value of Gold when executed.

This is the code link [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/47UbLws5gfpfC3RL0WPq?p=preview)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the code that isn't working specifically? What does "this is not working" mean, specifically? Show us the current result and the expected result so we can help.

Comment: @mjw explained my question briefly. thanks :)

Comment: So if i'm understanding you, the Gold column should not show all 8, right? You want to aggregate (max) that column's values and display the max in another column? Seems you should not set the aggFunc on the Gold column then. Create a "max" column and display it there. Personally I would return the max as another column in my back end query, but you haven't shown how the data is retrieved so I can't advise on that yet.